# "MongooseError: The uri parameter to openUri() must be a string. How to resolve when 'undefined'? - Node.js, MongoDB, Mongoose"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

"I'm encountering an issue with Mongoose when trying to connect to MongoDB in my Nest.js application. The error I'm facing is:
**MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined".
Can someone help me understand what might be causing this error and suggest steps to resolve it?

command:

```
docker run projectName
```

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM node:latest

# Create work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

# Copy app source to work directory
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install 

# Build
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run","start:dev" ]
```

docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I have tried the following:

1. Checked and confirmed that the MongoDB URI is correctly defined in my Node.js application.
2. Verified the Node.js and Mongoose versions to ensure compatibility.
3. Examined the Dockerfile to ensure it includes the necessary dependencies.
4. Reviewed the Docker run command for any potential issues in passing environment variables or mounting volumes.

- Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the MongooseError: The uriparameter toopenUri() must be a string, got 'undefined' error during the Docker run. My expectation is that the application should connect to MongoDB successfully when run in a Docker container, just as it does outside of Docker.
- Any guidance on additional steps I can take or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Comment: You should provide at-least the code in your application that handles the connection to the database, because the issue is there